# Macro that hides columns after a filter is applied

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a massive table with filters based on different criteria like 'state' and 'year'. I want to be able to filter the data and then have the macro hide all the columns that are empty. My current macro only hides columns that are completely empty. I want to be able to filter by 'year' and then use the macro to hide all the empty columns, even if there is data that's hidden by the filter.

```
Sub HideColumns()

Dim col As Range
For Each col In Columns("Q:KN")
If Application.Count(Range(Cells(6, col.Column), Cells(168, col.Column))) = 0 Then
col.Hidden = True
End If
Next

End Sub


Sub UnhideColumns()

Columns("Q:KN").Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe using special cells?`Application.Count(Range(Cells(6, col.Column),Cells(168, col.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))`

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` property will "make" a range composed of the non-hidden cells.  Try this:

```
If Application.Count(Range(Cells(6, col.Column), Cells(168, col.Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) = 0 then
```

Comment: @ChrisSir I accidentally deleted the "Then". Try it now

Comment: I fixed the "Then" When I ran the macro again I got a "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: It works for me. Please edit your original question and paste in the whole macro.

Comment: @ShawnV.Wilson line is the same line as mine, his should be working as well

Comment: I used what @Davesexcel suggested and it worked. Thank you for your help though

Comment: I'm glad it worked. (Because we suggested the same thing!)